# I have two different classes which uses @EnableScheduling but they are using same executor service

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I want both classes to use different executor services. but both are picking the same executor.

class implements SchedulingConfigurer

```
@Override
public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
    taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
}

@Bean()
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    taskScheduler.setPoolSize(2);
    taskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("taskScheduler1 - ");
    return taskScheduler;
}
```

Similarly in another class, I'm using this setup with setThreadNamePrefix as taskScheduler2.

But both the classes are using taskScheduler1

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to use different ThreadPoolTaskScheduler for two scheduled tasks. I think using @Async can do something similar. Put the business code in an asynchronous task and specify a different thread pool to run.